# "file is locked" when visual studio executes unit test

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I developed near 300 unit tests, but sometimes, when trying to develop new tests, or just execute old tests, I got below error (for some of assemblies):

```
Could not copy "X.dll" to "bin\Debug\X.dll". 
Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. 
The file is locked by: "Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (37736)"
```

After that only restarting visual studio resolves problem. Normally this error will be thrown when I changed tests or library and try to execute test again.

Any idea how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio resolved the problem for me also.